# Libgdx How do Block and Unblock Game Levels?

Tags: java, libgdx, levels

Im my level menu (I'm using libgdx), I would like to lock and unlock game levels.

Alowing player to unblock each game level after finishing the previous?.

Can someone point me an example?

Thanks in advance for any help comming this way.
PEACE!

Answer (score 1):

This is just logic stored in variables between sessions.

1. Loop all of your levels
2. If the loop index is lower then or equal than your variable "howManyLevelsComplete" make then unlocked. Else you lock them
3. Save the "howManyLevelsComplete" variable to Preferences so you can keep track when the application restarts.
4. I wont provide code for this since it's basic game logic.